# MoveWindow arguments - c# Func<>

Tags: c#, dllimport, func

I am trying to 'export' a c# function for use with IronPython and python for .Net. I have the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth,
int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
    public Func<> Main()
    {
        return MoveWindow;
    }
```

I am trying to pass the c# function to python (not my problem, handled by IronPython). My question is how do I know what to put in for the parameters of `Func<>`? I tried and got `Func<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,TResult>` as the structure and number of arguments. But that means that the type definitions given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) don't work, or are missing a few.

What are the types I am supposed to put in?? Or how do I find that out?

Comment: what is the return type of `MoveWindow`?

Comment: as on the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it is a bool

Comment: why are you trying to return a `Func<>`? it's not obvious from your question.

Comment: The fact that the MoveWindow declaration is public automatically makes it available for every .NET based language. `Main` declaration is used only for console/windows programs that get compiled into an exe an run on their own.

Comment: @Alejandro Main is not only used for that, its just *typically* used for that, there's nothing stopping somebody from having Main methods in other places.

Comment: I am returning it so I can use it from IronPython (hopefully)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature is

```
 bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

So it's a `Func<IntPtr, int, int, int, int, bool, bool>`.

The last type parameter of `Func` is the return type, as you can see in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd269654.aspx).

Comment: I am going to conditionally accept. I am getting `systemerror: object reference not set to an instance of an object`, but I don't think that is from your answer. Also, why did the compiler say that the function took T1-T9 if it actually took T1-T6?

Comment: Func has definitions from Func<TResult> to Func<T1...T16, TResult>, not sure how you got to that one in Intellisense but there are many to choose from.

Comment: @RonBeyer I didn't get it from Intellisense, I got it from an error when I tried `Func<IntPtr, int,int,int,int,bool>` I was really close!

Comment: @IronManMark20 Close only counts in horse shoes and hand grenades :)